# Nodemon not listening

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

I have added the nodemon dependency to the project. Made the main file as the server.js and have added the scripts as well on the package.json.

[image]

**Server.js**

[image]

While running the command npm run server - its giving the error below:

**Error Screen**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I'd say please don't post code as images, but in this case, it reveals the solution...

Your server code is `server/server.js` as far as the project root (where `package.json` is) is involved.

When you run `npm run` style scripts, the working directory will be the project root (and you can see as much in the `> file-upload@0.0.0 server ...` line) – that is, change your `server` script to

```
"scripts": {
  "server": "nodemon server/server.js"
},
```

and you should be golden.

Answer (score 2):

Paths follow the same pattern as node_modules. If you are refering to a file in your working directory you should call `nodemon ./server.js`

Answer (score 0):

Your server.js file is inside server folder so nodemon can't find it unless you give it the path, you can change the package.json script to this:

```
"server":"cd server && nodemon server.js"
```

Hope it solves the error.